# Completion of the proof of theorem 3.3 in Dale Husemoller: Elliptic Curves

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, elliptic-curves

I want to read the proof of the following theorem:

[image]

This is from p.35. But it is not complete there. There is written that:

[image]

Can someone tell me where I can find the rest of the proof?

Any other sources are also welcome :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is Exercise 10.19 of Chapter X of Silverman's "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves".

Answer (score 3):

**Claim**: Let $E: y^2=x^3+D$ and $p>3$ be a prime. Then, there is no point of order $p$ in $E(\mathbb{Q})$.

Here are some hints. Let $p>3$ be a prime as in the statement of the claim:

- If $q$ is a prime such that $q\equiv 2 \bmod 3$, and $q$ does not divide $6D$, then $E(\mathbb{F}_q)=q+1$.
- A prime $q$ that does not divide $6D$ is a prime of good reduction for $E$. Thus, $E(\mathbb{Q})[m]$ embeds into $E(\mathbb{F}_q)$ when $\gcd(m,q)=1$.
- In particular, if $E(\mathbb{Q})[p]$ is non-trivial, then $q+1$ is divisible by $p$, for all primes $q\equiv 2\bmod 3$ and $q>6D$. In other words, every prime $q\equiv 2 \bmod 3$ with $q>6D$ satisfies $q\equiv -1 \bmod p$ (contradiction!).

Comment: Thanks for your hints. I am at the step that #$E(\mathbb F_p)=p+1$ like in "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves", Ex. 10.19. Now $E(\mathbb Q)_{tors}$ can be seen as a subgroup of $E(\mathbb F_p)$, hence #$E(\mathbb Q)_{tors}$ divides $p+1$. For all $p=2$ (mod 3). With $p$ not dividing $6D$. How we can conclude now that #$E(\mathbb Q)_{tors}$ divides $6$? (as in Ex. 10.19 c) ) ?

Comment: Another question: According to your answer..How can I see that we got a contradiction?

Answer (score 2):

As **Álvaro Lozano-Robledo** already showed,
to prove that there is no $p$-torsion
it is enough to find a prime $q \not\mid 6D$ such that
$q \equiv 2 \bmod 3$ and $q \not\equiv -1 \bmod p$.
The punchline he left unstated is that the existence of such $q$
is guaranteed by 
[Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions)
on primes in arithmetic progressions.  Choose $m_0 \not\equiv 0, -1 \bmod p$
(say $m_0=1$).  By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, there exists
$m \equiv m_0 \bmod p$ such that $m \equiv 2 \bmod 3$.
Then $m$ is coprime to $3p$, so by Dirichlet there are
infinitely many primes $q \equiv m \bmod 3p$.
Since there are only finitely many factors of $6D$,
it follows that there are primes $q \equiv 2 \bmod 3$
that are neither factors of $6D$ nor congruent to $-1 \bmod p$,
and we're done.